# Google Sheet importxml - How to retrieve only the 5 first values?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to use Google Sheet's importxml function to get list of value, but only need first 12 value.

So how can I do it, please?

My query: `=IMPORTXML("https://muagame.vn/may-ps4.html","//h3")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from the URL of `https://muagame.vn/may-ps4.html` with the xpath of `//h3`.
- When the xpath of `//h3` is used, 12 items are retrieved. You want to retrieve the 1st 5 items.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, the xpath is modified. Please modify the xpath of `=IMPORTXML("https://muagame.vn/may-ps4.html","//h3")` as follows.

#### From:

```
//h3
```

#### To:

```
//li[position()<=5]/h3
```

- In the HTML data, the tag `h3` is put in the tag `li`. So in order to retrieve the 1st 5 items of `h3`, I used `li[position()<=5]`.

#### Result:

[image]

In this case, the formula is `=IMPORTXML("https://muagame.vn/may-ps4.html","//li[position()<=5]/h3")`.

#### Reference:

- [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://muagame.vn/may-ps4.html", "//h3"), "limit 5")
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML("https://muagame.vn/may-ps4.html", "//h3"), 5, 1)
```